# polynomial equation solve in full numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, square-numbers

$x^2+x+41=y^2$ <--solve that in full numbers.
I get to that point
$(y-sq(x))(y+sq(x)))=x+41$
which imo must be false because this implies that $sq(x)^2$ is equal to $-x$ did I make a mistake somewhere
Ok I can't solve it, I'll have some help

Comment: There are two variables here.  Are you supposed to express one of them ($y$ maybe?) in terms of the other?  Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: Hint: For all x,  $x^2 + (x+1) = (x+1)^2 - x$

Comment: Or are you supposed to find all solutions where $x$ and $y$ are integers?  The term “full numbers” is uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply your original equation by $4$ to obtain $$4x^2+4x+164=4y^2$$

Then complete the square on the left $$(2x+1)^2+163=4y^2$$

Now rearrange to obtain the difference of two squares
$$(2y)^2-(2x+1)^2=163$$Factorise the difference of two squares $$(2y+2x+1)(2y-2x-1)=163$$

If this is to be solved in integers, note that $163=163\times 1=-163\times -1$

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I _was_ going to say that, but the OP said they wanted to solve it themself. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring I haven't fully solved the question. My thinking was that OP was trying to get a factorisation from the difference of two squares, but hadn't worked out how to get a good one. The technique of completing the square is worth noting, to deal with all the $x, y$ terms at once, so you end up factorising an integer.

Comment: guys I don't have an idea what to do with that $(2y+2x+1)(2y−2x−1)=163$ could you explain me more, I was trying to understand it but I can't

Comment: Understood, Mark. I was hoping that my hint would lead the OP towards completing the squares. I guess the slightly tricky bit is realising that you need to multiply to avoid getting fractions.

Comment: @II: $163$ is a prime, so one of $(2y+2x+1)$ and $(2y−2x−1)$ must be equal to $\pm163$, and the other must equal $\pm1$.

Comment: @PM2Ring lol thanks of course